# How to retrieve data from localStorage in JS from multiple radio buttons after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first question so.. be gentle and I'm sorry if there is some mistake. Thank you.

I have groups of radio buttons and this is the HTML:

```
<div class="radio">
   <label for="a_a">
       <input type="radio" name="some_name" id="a_a" value="some_value">
   </label>
   <label for="a_b">
       <input type="radio" name="some_name" id="a_b" value="some_value">
   </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
   <label for="b_b">
       <input type="radio" name="some_name" id="b_b" value="some_value">
   </label>
   <label for="b_c">
       <input type="radio" name="some_name" id="b_c" value="some_value">
   </label>
</div>
```

and this is the JS:

```
$(".radio label").on('click', function (e) {
     var input_id = $(this).children().attr('id');
     var input_value = $(this).children().attr('value');
     localStorage.setItem(input_value, input_id);
});
var itemID = localStorage.getItem("option");
    if (itemID !== null) {
        $("input[id=\"" + itemID + "\"]").click();
};
```

This works well, but the problem is that I'm getting the id only of the last clicked radio button and the question is: How to get the id's from both groups of radio buttons. Please, be aware that there might be more than 2 groups of radio buttons.

Thank you.

Comment: This is because localstorage only works with a key=> value pair and cannot be used as an array. To do so, you can create a json object and assign it to a key => Json.stringify(object). On retrieving end, you would do Json.Parse(localstorage.getItem(key)).

Comment: @CaptainRed thank you, I'll try that, but it seems I'll have to read more about that kind of solution, because I've tried with array also, but didn't work well again.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Also, it is not clear as to what you are trying to achieve here. Could you explain more and/or edit your question accordingly?

Comment: Sure. When you click on some of the radio buttons, the js manipulate window.location.hash and by the id's from those radio buttons I use ajax to get the items (products) and be shown in the browser without reloading the page itself, but when I refresh the page the selected radio buttons are not selected anymore and the id's from the window.location.hash(url) also disappear. With the code I posted above everything works fine, but only if one radio button is selected. I hope that makes some sense.

Comment: You should try posting the whole code portion that deals with it. Here you are setting the localstorage as: localStorage.setItem(input_value, input_id); and retrieving it as: var itemID = localStorage.getItem("option"); How is the input_value and "option" related?

Comment: Is not related at all, I've just tried 'something' to see how it will/not work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/15/

what do you want to do with the values?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){    
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).val();
       localStorage.setItem(id, value);
    }); 
}
window.onload = function() { 
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){    
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       var getValue = localStorage.getItem(id);
       alert("value = "+getValue+" id = "+id);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: So here you go, all those radio buttons are loaded from json file(with different key, value) via js to the html, all the radio buttons are with different ID's (you know why), when you select one radio button from each group and refresh the page, the radio buttons you've selected before the reload, should stay selected after page reload.